# Attribute Error due to filtering a dataset based on a certain period that does not exist in the dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to filter a dataset based on current quarter, but what do I need to do IF there is no data available for this quarter? Is there a function that I need to include? Can I use IF Else function..?

Currently, I'm getting an Attribute error message saying:
**AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'**

| ID | Effective Date | Quarter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2023-05-01 | 2023Q2 |
| 02 | 2023-03-01 | 2023Q1 |

```
def quarter_finder():
    global s
    m=datetime.today().month
    y=datetime.today().year
    yq4=datetime.today().year
    if m in (10,11,12):
        s=str(yq4)+'Q4'
    elif m in (1,2,3):
        s=str(y)+'Q1'
    elif m in (4,5,6):
        s =str(y)+'Q2'
    else:
        s =str(y)+'Q3'
    return s
ss=quarter_finder()


df.effective_dt = pd.to_datetime(df.effective_dt)
df['quarter'] = df['effective_dt'].dt.to_period('Q')

df = df[df['quarter'].apply(str).contains(ss)]
```

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

The errors says that you are trying to run a non-existent method, not that you don't have the appropriate data in the dataframe.

The correct syntax:

```
df = df[df['quarter'].apply(str).str.contains(ss)]
```

If you don't have a certain period in the dataframe, the result will be just empty.

Comment: I get another error - AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I've updated the answer. `.apply(str)` from your try was on point.